# Serving documents outside the web root folder.

Tags: php, pdf

I have a function called "viewDoc" which is supposed to go to a folder outside the web root and fetch a file for me. It seams to work ok with images (Jpgs etc) but with PDF's it just outputs a blank gray page as demonstrated here - http://www.tutorplanner.com/userimage/viewdoc/12787622467.pdf

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong as I've been scratching my head over this for a day!

```
public function viewDoc($doc) {

        $path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $file = $doc;
        $fileDir = '/var/uploads/';

        if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
        {

            $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file);
            //print_r($contents);
            header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($fileDir . $file));
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileDir . $file));
            readfile($contents);
        }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is used with the parameter of a file name - NOT text.

Two examples that would work (file_get_contents):

```
public function viewDoc($doc) {

        $path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $file = $doc;
        $fileDir = '/var/uploads/';
        $filePath = $fileDir . $file;

        if (file_exists($filePath))
        {
            $contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
            header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filePath));
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
            echo $contents;
        }
}
```

or (readfile):

```
public function viewDoc($doc) {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $file = $doc;
        $fileDir = '/var/uploads/';
        $filePath = $fileDir . $file;

        if (file_exists($filePath))
        {
            header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filePath));
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
            readfile($filePath);
        }
}
```

I also added the `$filePath` variable for you, as there's no reason to concat the string multiple times.

**Edit**

As extra security, to Yazmat's comment, you can use `$file = str_replace(array('..', '/'), '', $doc);` as this would remove all references to other directories (however, with the slash it would also remove access to sub directories, so you might want to skip that, dependend on your code and file structure).

Comment: hi h2oooooo, How would you add the $file = str_replace(array('..', '/'), '', $doc); to the function? I have tried using that to replace the line $file = $doc; but it just seams to break the file. any idea?

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand What's the content of `$doc`? If it has slashes in it, you need to use `$file = str_replace('..', '', $doc);` instead, as else you'd be replacing the forward slash with nothing. This means that people would still be able to get into a subfolder of `/var/uploads` but not any other directory (as `../` means "One directory back").

Answer (score 0):

You have a great security issue here, anyone can access anything on your server with the function you wrote. I realy advise you to not use it and just put your files (that should be accessible) on a public web directory.