# How to Hide a html-file on the internet

Tags: html

Lets say i have a webb-server. With a domain. Exampel.com and i have a html file on that server. Exampel.com/hidden/name.html

What actions could i take if i wanted this "name.html" never to be found by anyone. Except if i give you the correct URL.

The only thing i can come up with is naming it something very obscure like; xxvpe.html

Obviusly this is a HTML file you need to pay to see. And i know i could hide it using PHP but for this project it wouldent work. It needs to be on the web,

Thankful for any suggestions!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to "hide" files is to move them out of the web root and deliver them through a proxy that will check some authentication and then send the MIME header and stream out the file upon success.

See: [Serving documents outside the web root folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843950/serving-documents-outside-the-web-root-folder)

Security through obscurity is a bad policy.

Answer (score 0):

Without authentication it is impossible to hide it!

Sure, I's very unlikely someone will guess the URL, but anyone with URL will be able to access it. Also if you want to hide it not to appear on Google, you can do this for example by using

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
```

in your HTML file

Comment: What fo you mean with authentication? ;)

Comment: Something like asking for username and password, so PHP or server auth, or whatever...